# Python: assign values to variables in a list or object

Tags: python

I want to do the following:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
tom = [a,b,c]
for i in tom:
    i = 6
```

The desired result is `a = 6`

The actual result is `a = 1`

I'm guessing that there is no way to do this without some kind of exec. Correct?

Comment: Should `tom` be `[6, 6, 6]` then? Do you know that the result of `tom = [a,b,c]` is `[1, 2, 3]`? The reference to the original variable is lost, setting a new value for each element in the list won't update the original variable.

Comment: that won't change your list "tom" either.  With more details about what you're trying to do exactly I can give you some better solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initially I misunderstood your question, and I see that kindall got it right. But I think this question shows a need for a more detailed explanation of how Python works. The best way to think about variables in Python is to think of variable names as having *arrows* attached to them, and values as objects to which those arrows point. Variable names point to objects. So when you do this:

```
a = 1
```

You're really saying "`a` points to `1`". And when you do this:

```
b = a
```

You're really saying "`b` points to the same object as `a`". Under normal circumstances, a variable can't point to another variable name; it can only point at the same object that the other variable points at. So when you do this:

```
tom = [a, b, c]
```

You aren't creating a list that points to the *variable names* `a`, `b`, and `c`; you're creating a list that points to the same objects as `a`, `b`, and `c`. If you change where `a` points, it has no effect on where `tom[0]` points. If you change where `tom[0]` points, it has no effect on where `a` points.

Now, as others have pointed out, you *can* programmatically alter the values of variable names, ether using `exec` as you suggested (not recommended), or by altering `globals()` (also not recommended). But most of the time, it's just not worth it.

If you really want to do this, my suggestion would be either simply to use a dictionary (as suggested by [DzinX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8990208/577088)) or, for a solution that's closer to the spirit of your question, and still reasonably clean, you could simply use a mutable object. Then you could use `getattr` and `setattr` to programmatically alter the attributes of that object like so:

```
>>> class Foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.a = 1
>>> setattr(f, 'b', 2)
>>> getattr(f, 'a')
1
>>> f.b
2
```

Generally, the best solution is to just use a dictionary. But occasionally situations might arise in which the above is better.

Answer (score 5):

`tom = [a, b, c]` puts the values 1, 2, and 3 into the list. Once these values are in the list, there's no way to know what name(s) are pointing to them. Assuming they are global variables, you *could* (but almost certainly shouldn't) do this:

```
tom = ["a", "b", "c"]
for n in tom:
    globals()[n] = 1
```

Trying to set individual variables in a loop is almost always the wrong approach. The values clearly have something in common, otherwise you wouldn't want to change them all in a loop, so *store them in a list (or a dictionary, if you need names for them)* and access and change them there, instead of using individual variables.

Comment: Or use a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: No. No no no no. This is a horrible and sick way and you should not be teaching this. Infact the normal python user does not even need to know that `globals()` is defined.

Comment: I answered the question (since it is in fact answerable and a *documented feature of the language),* told him it's a bad way to do it, and suggested better ways. I'll edit to add some additional caution earlier on, but geez.

Answer (score 2):

More concisely,

```
a, b, c = map(lambda x: 6, [1, 2, 3])
```

or

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
a, b, c = map(lambda x: 6, [a, b, c])
```

which could easily be generalised if you want to assign each to different values based on their original values.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you didn't use variables, but keys in the dictionary, like this:

```
values = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
}

for k in values:
    values[k] = 6

print values['a']
# prints: 6
```

If you want to change only some values, use:

```
for k in ['a', 'c']:
    values[k] = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea.

```
seniority = [range(1, 6)]
people = ["Richard", "Rob", "Steve", "Terry", "Micah"]
people = seniority
print people
```

output: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]]