# How to transform a list element in a variable

Tags: python, list

I did a list of x elements `(a, b, c,...x,)` and I now want to turn them into variable like `a = 2.` This is so I can later call them in my code by their name since I want to do some operation like `a + b.`
This might be the wrong way to do it but I just can't find a solution.

For those interested, I'm doing this since I want a program that can calculate the chance % of a player to win a card tournament with a line up of different decks. This is my code so far, `"Listemu"` is the list I then want to turn elements into variables (like, `"deck0deck01 = 60"`).

```
nbdeck = input("Nombre de deck :")
nbdeck = int(nbdeck)
i = 0
Listedeck=[]
while i < nbdeck :
    Listedeck.append('deck'+str(i))
    i += 1
i = 0
a = 0
Listemu=[]
for elt in Listedeck :
    while i < nbdeck :
        Listemu.append('deck'+str(a)+'deck'+str(i))
        i += 1
    a += 1
    i = 0
```

Here I want to insert every % of two decks match up like `deck0` against `deck1 = 60%` for `deck0` (created in `Listemu` under `"deck0deck1"` name) to call the % when I simulate the confrontation.

Comment: This is exactly what `dictionaries` are there for. They are used to assign values to keys. Your keys would be `a`, `b`, `c`, ... `x` and your values can be about anything. From then on whenever you need the value instead of the key, you use the `dict` to look them up.

Comment: How do you want the values to be assigned?

Comment: Also: [Python: assign values to variables in a list or object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989801/python-assign-values-to-variables-in-a-list-or-object)

Comment: Also: [How to assign values to variables in a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652427/how-to-assign-values-to-variables-in-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of elements and I am assuming you have a list of `values` already. 
What you need is a dictionary that will create a `key-value` pair.

Something like:

```
elem_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
val_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

dictionary_ = dict(zip(elem_list, val_list))
print(dictionary_)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

and then:

```
#access the value of a dictionary with its key
print(dictionary_["a"])   # output: 1
```

you could then even assign it to a variable:

```
a = dictionary_["a"]   # a = 1
```